# ESP8266 - AP+STA mode not working properly

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266

I'm trying to have an ESP8266 ESP-12 to serve as Access Point and Station at the same time, delivering the same webpage in both cases.
This is what I have:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP.h>

const byte DNS_PORT = 53;
DNSServer dnsServer;

MDNSResponder mdns;
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

String ssid = "";
String password = "";
String webPage = "";


void setup(void){

  IPAddress Ip(192, 168, 1, 1);
  IPAddress NMask(255, 255, 255, 0);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(Ip, Ip, NMask);
  WiFi.softAP(conf_ssid.c_str());
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Soft AP Started");
  Serial.println("");

  /* Setup the DNS server redirecting all the domains to the Ip */  
  dnsServer.setErrorReplyCode(DNSReplyCode::NoError);
  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "www.example.com", Ip);

  //connectToWifi();
  getCredentials(); //Reads Home WiFi credentials from the EEPROM
  if (ssid != "" and password != ""){
    WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), password.c_str());
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  }
  server.begin();

  // When no password is present
  if ((ssid == "" and password == "") or (ssid == "Error")){
    // ****** MAIN PAGE ******
    server.on("/", [](){ /* HANDLES CREDENTIAL INPUT */   });
    server.begin();
  }
  else // If we have ssid and password -- check if we have connection
  {
    webPage += "<h1>Main Webpage</h1>";
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    server.begin();
    //if (mdns.begin("esp8266", WiFi.localIP())) {
     // Serial.println("MDNS responder started");
    //}

    server.on("/", [](){
      server.send(200, "text/html", webPage);
    });
    Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  }
}

void loop(void){
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Basically, it reads the credentials from the EEPROM, if there is no credential, a WiFi configuration page is displayed, otherwise it also connects to the WiFi serving the Main Webpage to both AP and Station.

The issue is that, even though I can see the AP and a ping from my PC to the WiFi Station's Ip works, I can only access the webpage if I'm connected via AP, not via Station.
Any thoughts?

Many thanks.

Comment: if you comment out the dns stuff can you connect as STA?

Comment: If i comment out that, nothing changes. I still can connect as STA but the web page isn't displayed

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work around the problem which is working for me for quiet a bit.The solution is to create 2 servers one with the station IP and another with the AP IP. The problem which occurs here is the AP is being created immediately as the board is being switched on but it takes time to connect to a station. So the Server doesn't know that it has to serve both the IPs when a request is being made.

I do have a LUA code ready:

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATIONAP)

ap = {}
sta = {}
ap_ip = {}
conn_table = {}

ap.ssid = "Node-Mcu1"
ap.pwd = "123456789"

sta.ssid = "Home WIFI"
sta.pwd = "iforgotmypassword"

ap_ip.ip = "192.168.1.1"
ap_ip.netmask = "255.255.255.0"
ap_ip.gateway = "192.168.0.2"

wifi.sta.sethostname("ESP8266")
wifi.ap.setip(ap_ip)
wifi.ap.config(ap)
wifi.sta.config(sta)
wifi.sta.connect()


timer1 = tmr.create()
timer1:alarm(1000,tmr.ALARM_AUTO ,function()
    conn_table = wifi.ap.getclient()
    --[[ GET THE IF ADDRESSES OF ALL CONNECCTED MODULES
    for mac,ip in pairs(conn_table) do
        print(mac,ip)
    end --]]
end
)

server1 = net.createServer(net.TCP,120)
server2 = net.createServer(net.TCP,120)
LEDpin = 2
gpio.mode(LEDpin, gpio.OUTPUT)



function SendHTML(sck, led) -- Send LED on/off HTML page
   htmlstring = "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."<html>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."<head>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."<title>LED Control</title>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."</head>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."<body>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."<h1>LED</h1>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."<p>Click to switch LED on and off.</p>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."<form method=\"get\">\r\n"
  if (led)  then
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."<input type=\"button\" value=\"LED OFF\" onclick=\"window.location.href='/ledoff'\">\r\n"
  else
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."<input type=\"button\" value=\"LED ON\" onclick=\"window.location.href='/ledon'\">\r\n"
  end
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."</form>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."</body>\r\n"
   htmlstring = htmlstring.."</html>\r\n"
   sck:send(htmlstring)
end

function receiver(sck, data)-- process callback on recive data from client
print(data)
  if string.find(data, "GET /ledon")  then
   SendHTML(sck, true)
   gpio.write(LEDpin, gpio.HIGH)
  elseif string.find(data, "GET / ") or string.find(data, "GET /ledoff") then
   SendHTML(sck, false)
   gpio.write(LEDpin, gpio.LOW)
  else
   sck:send("<h2>Not found...!!</h2>")
   sck:on("sent", function(conn) conn:close() end)
  end
end

if server1 then
    print(wifi.ap.getip())
  server1:listen(80,wifi.ap.getip(), function(conn)-- listen to the port 80
  conn:on("receive", receiver) 

  end)
end

timer = tmr.create()
timer:alarm(1000,tmr.ALARM_AUTO ,function()
    if wifi.sta.getip() == nil then
        print("Obtaining IP...")
    else
        timer:stop()
        timer:unregister()
        print("Got IP. "..wifi.sta.getip())
        if server2 then
          print("server2")
          server2:listen(80,wifi.sta.getip(), function(conn)-- listen to the port 80
          conn:on("receive", receiver) 

          end)
        end

    end        
end
)
```